# PHP Form Validation and POST variables

Tags: php, post

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying some form validation. I have the following code:

I submit a form and submit the data to an SQL statement if it passes validation.  If the form is valid, it redirects to an external success page.

What I can't do is get the original post variables onto the success page. How could I do this please?  My code is below:

PHP:

```
   <body>
<?php

$firstnameErr = $emailErr = $lastnameErr = $gradeErr = $roleErr = "";
$firstname = $email = $lastname = $grade = $role = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
        $firstnameErr = "First name is required";
    } else {
        $firstname = user_input($_POST["firstname"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
        $lastnameErr = "Last mame is required";
    } else {
        $lastname = user_input($_POST["lastname"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = user_input($_POST["email"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["grade"])) {
        $gradeErr = "Grade is required";
    } else {
        $grade = user_input($_POST["grade"]);
    }


    if (empty($_POST["role"])) {
        $roleErr = "Role is required";
    } else {
        $role = user_input($_POST["role"]);
    }

    if($firstnameErr == '' && $emailErr == '' && $lastnameErr == '' && $gradeErr == '' && $roleErr == ''){

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `Tom`.`staff_details` (`first_name`, `surname`, `role`, `grade`,`email`) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname','$role', '$grade','$email');");
        $stmt->execute();
        header('Location: staff_added.php');
        exit();
    };

}

function user_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
        <label>First name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" />
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span><br>
        <label>Last name:</label><input type="text" name="lastname" />
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $lastnameErr;?></span><br>
        <label>Role:</label><input type="text" name="role" />
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $roleErr;?></span><br>
        <label>Grade:</label><input type="text" name="grade" />
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $gradeErr;?></span><br>
        <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" />
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br><br>
        <input class="standard_submit" type="submit" value="Save" id="submit_search_button">
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

I would like those variables to move across to the staff_added.php page so that I can print them back to the user.  I've done some reading over this but as far, it's not making much sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You need to either store some of the info in a session, or store the users ID and load the data from your db on the success page. - There are multiple ways of doing it, these are just a couple of them.

Comment: You are entirely missing the point of `prepared statements` by directly embedding variables in the sql statement rather than using placeholders to which you would bind the variables

Comment: I see those `user_input()` functions a lot of places, and like it is here, it's somewhat misunderstood and misused.

Comment: I've seen an online example within W3schools to get me started but the explanation there is pretty vague.  The prepared statements will come next when I start refactoring with more understanding, I'm just going one step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the variables in a **SESSION** object and then will be available from everywhere :

```
<?php
session_start();
//other code...
$_SESSION["role"] = $role; 
//other code...
?>
```

Comment: Would I need to declare the end of the session in the confirmation page?

Comment: You should use **session_destroy()** , in your case i think you shouldn't call it in your page , [read here](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/10/3/5/ending-a-session)

Comment: You could use `$_SESSION[ 'formdata' ]=$_POST` and then access the elements using `$_SESSION[ 'formdata' ]['role']` etc rather than individual session variables

Answer (score 1):

Using `prepared statements` you should be looking at an approach like this perhaps rather than directly embedding variables in the sql.

```
<?php
    function user_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
    $firstname = $email = $lastname = $grade = $role = false;

    if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {
        $errors=array();


        if( empty($_POST["firstname"])) $errors[] = "First name is required";
        else $firstname = user_input( $_POST["firstname"] );


        if( empty($_POST["lastname"])) $errors[] = "Last mame is required";
        else $lastname = user_input($_POST["lastname"]);


        if( empty($_POST["email"])) $errors[] = "Email is required";
        else $email = user_input($_POST["email"]);


        if( empty($_POST["grade"]) ) $errors[] = "Grade is required";
        else $grade = user_input($_POST["grade"]);



        if( empty($_POST["role"])) $errors[] = "Role is required";
        else $role = user_input( $_POST["role"] );


        if( empty( $errors ) ){

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `Tom`.`staff_details` (`first_name`, `surname`, `role`, `grade`,`email`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);");
            if( $stmt ){
                $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$firstname,$lastname,$role,$grade,$email);
                $stmt->execute();

                exit( header( 'Location: staff_added.php' ) );
            } else { echo 'statement failed'; }


        } else {
            foreach( $errors as $error )echo $error . '<br />';
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when applying this code. My connection uses PDO and it tells me that bind_params is an undefined method for PDO

Comment: I found bindParam which worked. Thank for the help with prepared statements

Comment: Sorry - my mistake ~ I thought you were using `mysqli` rather than PDO